# Matrix Norms - Burden and Faires(Page 439)

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Burden and Faires define:

> If $\|\cdot\|$ is a vector norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then
>
> $$\|A\|=\max_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|.$$

In other words, the measure given to a matrix under such a norm describes how the matrix stretches unit vectors of length $1$ ($\|x\|=1$), relative to that norm. The norm of the matrix is the maximum stretch.

They illustrate by means of an example, for the matrix

$$A =\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 \\
2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Graphically, the matrix norm is:

[image: Matrix norms]

The image of the vector any vector $x=(x_1,x_2)$ is $Ax=(-2x_2,2x_1)$. When I plugged in some vectors $(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)$ for the $l_\infty$ norm as well as some others like $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ for the $l_2$ norm, I don't get the parallelogram or the ellipse. Could someone help me visualize this better? I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: It is indeed true that the transformation visualized in the figures is not the transformation described by your matrix $A$.  In the case of the matrix $A$, the resulting parallelogram should be a rotated square and the resulting ellipse should be a circle.

Answer (score 2):

It is the wrong matrix. One can relatively easily reconstruct a matrix from the first image, as the sides of the unit square map to the sides of the parallelogram. Assume that the orientation is preserved, as it is in the given matrix. From the top and bottom sides as images of $x=\pm 1$, $y\in[-1,1]$, the $y$ component of the image is more like $1.3x$ and in the left side as image of $y=1$, $x\in[-1,1]$ the $x$ component varies from $-2$ at $x=1$ to about $-1.2$ at $x=-1$, giving a formula like $-0.4x-1.6y$, (on the other hand, the intercept with the $x$-axis is at about $-1.5$,...) so that 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}-0.4&-1.6\\1.3&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

[image]

```
def plot_A(x,y):
    plt.plot(-(0.3*x+1.5*y),1.3*x); plt.grid();
    plt.xlim(-2.1,2.1); plt.ylim(-1.4,1.4)

plt.figure(figsize=(2*3,2));
x=np.array([1,-1,-1, 1,1]);
y=np.array([1, 1,-1,-1,1]);
plt.subplot(1,2,1); plot_A(x,y);
phi=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200);
x,y = np.cos(phi), np.sin(phi);
plt.subplot(1,2,2); plot_A(x,y);
plt.tight_layout(); plt.show();
```

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Yes, there was another error in transforming the picture into a matrix. The plots show that the book took another matrix for the ellipse, or they just drew in some vector plot program a suitable ellipse with an arrow inside, without regard to any matrix.

Comment: In fact with a more vertical slope for the second line (eg with $0.4 \to 0.3$ and $1.6 \to 1.7$), you end up with a parallelogram and ellipse that are closer to the graphics shown in the book.  I do ultimately suspect that the two figures correspond to the same transformation.